# tkinter window not showing up even though its installed

Tags: python, tkinter

hi I have my program running with 0 errors but the window from tkinter is not showing I checked if it's installed and checked my version of python can anyone let me know what else it could be?

Comment: How can we know without seeing your code?

Comment: import numpy as np
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("9x9 grid")
window.geometry("420x420")
entries=[]
for a in range(0, 420, 140):
    for b in range(0, 420, 140):
        bttn1=tkinter.Button(window)
        bttn1.place(x=a,y=b,width=140,height=140)
        entries.append(bttn1)
window.mainloop

Comment: Post the code in the question and not in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Change `window.mainloop` to `window.mainloop()`  That calls mainloop instead of just referencing it.